# Why am I getting segmentation fault while dynamically allocating in c?

Tags: c, string

This is my code and when I run it, I am getting segmentation fault.

```
 char *s = NULL;
s = (char *)malloc(5*sizeof(char));

s[0]='10';

s[1]='20';

printf("%s",s[1]);
```

please tell where the error is and why this is happening. My intension of the program is to dynamically create a string, give it some value byte by byte and print the values byte by byte.

Is there any way to add integer values to string. Because, I have a situation where length of string is to be in first part of string followed by data. Kindly suggest any method to do this in C.

Comment: Your string isn't null terminated, so using `%s` is going to lead to unhappiness.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing multibyte characters in `s[0]` and `s[1]`. Beside of this use `%c` format specifier to print a character.

Comment: And printing a `char` with `%s`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, what is not wrong, the multibyte assignment or the `printf` part?

Comment: sorry, thought we were in c++ for some reason. vote redacted :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, in C it is implementation-defined behavior, **J.3.4** `The value of a wide character constant containing more than one multibyte character, or containing a multibyte character or escape sequence not represented in the extended execution character set.` What about C++?

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%s", s[1]);` means print string starting at *address* (int)'20'. That's clearly a bug. Should be: `s[2]='\0'; printf("%s", s+1 /*&s[1]*/);`

Comment: Okay, I got it. My problem is to pack the string with length and followed by data. for eg: "5hello". How to do this in C?

Comment: @mit23 To emulate Pascal-string? What for? You will be unable to use C-library "as is". For example, simply to print such string: `for(i=1,j=s[0]; j>0; i++, j--) printf("%c", s[i]);` - isn't it ugly?

Comment: @user4419802 true, but the simpler `for(i=1; i<=s[0]; i++) printf("%c", s[i]);` is less ugly.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK, my code was a bit sloppy. BTW, it's better not to use `printf` at all: `for(i=1; i<=s[0]; i++) putchar(s[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

1.`s[0]` is a `char` you can not assign `10` to it. (It will compile with warnings but it is not doing what you have expected)

2.`printf("%s",s[1]);` will also cause undefined behavior as string followed by`s[1]` is not null terminated.

Comment: actually with all the long responses here , this is the most accurate and short answer to the original OP question . you got my upvote

Answer (score 0):

[Don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)  the result of malloc and family.

`s[0]` and `s[1]` will take only one byte value.

Then your string is not a null terminated string.

Try this.

```
  s[0]='h';
  s[1]='i'; 
  s[2]='\0'; 

  printf("%s",s);
```

`%s` is for printing the string. Use `%c` for printing the character.

```
  printf("%c",s[1]);
```

You can use like this to store the integer into an `char` array,

```
 char *s=malloc(123);
 sprintf(s,"%d",integer_value);
```

Then use `strcat` to store the string in that.

Passing to the function use like this,

```
   void func(char *);
   main() { 
      . . .
       func(s);
      . . .
   }
   void func(char *str)
    { 
         // do what you need
    }
```

if between integer and string slash is available ( like in your comment) you can use the `strtok` function. Before using the `strtok` function take backup for your string. It will modify your content. Or els you can use like this,

```
  sscanf(str,"%d / %s",&int,string);
```

Now string have the value `"hello"`.

```
  char s[10];
  sprintf(s,"%d",int);
  strcat(str,s);
```

Try this,

```
    int fd;

    char str[]="data7";
    char st[12];

    sscanf(str,"%[^ 0-9] %d",st,&fd);
    printf("st:%s\tfd:%d\n",st,fd);
```

Comment: You can assign like that; the result is implementation defined, but that doesn't make it illegal.

Comment: Is there any significance to 123 or it is just a random number?

Comment: You can allocate memory you need. It just for example.

Comment: Okay! Then how to extract the length part from string? I should pass this string to a function where it will extract the length part and does some processing to string.

Comment: You can use the `strlen` function to get the length of the string.

Comment: Instead, let my string is "5/hello". Now, I want to get "hello" from this. Can you please suggest to do this?

Comment: I didn't get that scanf("%d / %s",&int,string). Please be patient enough to explain this.

Comment: Sorry use the `sscanf`. Or I have to explain?

Comment: Thank you! Now, Can I pack the string like "hello5", i.e., data followed by length?

Comment: Try like this, `sscanf(str,"%[^0-9] %d",string,&int);`

Comment: My question is how to concat a integer value to a string? strcat(string,int) will not work right?

Comment: You can do. But you need an one extra variable. See the answer.

Comment: I have a string "7hai". I want 7 and hai seperated. Please provide the line of code which does this. I tried what all you told.

Comment: Sorry bro! I have it like "data7". I need them to be seperated.

Comment: can I do this without creating another string? If no, please tell me how to do this by creating the additional string dynamically using malloc, instead of s[10].